# Move customized google map marker above the latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Please let me know how to move customized google map marker above the latitude and longitude point?

Here is the JSBIN : [Link](http://jsbin.com/pinevuba/1/edit), here i have used three object arrays, just used this link to understated the coding structure,

Please let me know where i have to insert "anchor" to position customized icon?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `anchor` property of the [icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon) and add any offset you need for the marker image.

```
var iconObj = {
    url: '/path/to/icon.png', //path to icon image
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //position of the image within a sprite
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25), //position at which to anchor an icon in correspondance to the position of the marker
};

var markerObj = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point, 
    map: map, 
    icon: iconObj
});
```

**Update:**

To answer your second question 'where do I put this exactly in my code' - you should put icon as an object in `drivers` array instead of a string.

Here's [modified working version of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/68hsC/)